# How to Add sound to UIPickerView programmatically

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview

I can't figure out how to add a ticking sound to a UIPickerView that I have declared programmatically. In @package , struct of UIPickerView I found a member variable called "unsigned int soundsDisabled:1;" but I cannot seem to access it.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Ryan Wong

Edit some COde:

```
-(void)initializeGame {
self.startTime = [NSDate date]; // Load the current time into startTime...

// create UIPickerView
UIPickerView *myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 650, 768, 216)];
myPickerView.delegate = self;
myPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

[self.view addSubview:myPickerView];
[self resetStats];
```

}

Comment: give a some sample code

Comment: And one thing some apple default setting should be changing. Apple should be rejected the app from app store. be careful before implementation understood apple Terms and condition for app store

Answer (score 2):

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/scrollerClick.wav

Multimedia Approach:

```
SystemSoundID soundID;

    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:effectTitle ofType:@"caf"];
    NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];

    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID ((CFURLRef)soundUrl, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

Comment: Hi iDev, what would you like to see in my code? Everything is working fine except for the fact that I do not know how to enable sound to my UIPickerView that I created programatically.

Comment: @RyanCW There is no any UIPickerView delegates methods if you want go with multimedia approach.

Comment: hmm what do you mean by that ? how do i use this approach to add sound to my uipickerview

Comment: I have already tried that but how are you going to add that to your UIPickerView :S ?